# Building the library for check test C framework

Tags: c, makefile, check-framework

I started to use **check** framework for testing C application.
For better understanding I went across the example in check package. It is working fine, but I don't need the automake tools - I want to compile it by my own Makefile (since I want to understand the check properly and I need to use my final application as a package of an OS). Maybe I could use there the autogenerated Makefile, but for now, it would be next one new thing I have to learn and I have restricted time for preparing unit tests. (Then, of course, I want to study and understand the tools for generating Makfile, using configure, etc.)

There is a problem in building application with my Makefile, that I don't have linked the object for check functionality:

```
/tmp/ccm7cniy.o: In function `test_money_create':
check_money.c:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `tcase_fn_start'
check_money.c:(.text+0x79): undefined reference to `_fail_unless'
check_money.c:(.text+0xcc): undefined reference to `_fail_unless'
```

I found out, that in the example application is the gcc with obj. file `check_money-check_money.o`, which was created by gcc:

```
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..     -g -O2 -MT check_money-check_money.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/check_money-check_money.Tpo -c -o check_money-check_money.o `test -f'check_money.c' || echo './'`check_money.c
```

And here is my problem: it uses the dependency `check_money-check_money.Tpo`. This file was generating by the command `./configure`, which I don't use.

How can I create my own `.o` file for check to build successfully? It is necessary to create this file for every application? Could not be one, somewhere in shared libraries?

(I am sorry if my question is "stupid", I have small experience by building applications in linux yet)

Comment: Have you installed the check framework? If you have, you could try using `pkg-config` say `gcc check_money.c \`pkg-config --cflags --libs check\``

Comment: the gcc option `-MF bla.Tpo` contains the building dependencies, [see here -M](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options). So if you correctly specify all libs and dependencies by hand you don't need that. Judging from the error, you don't link versus the check library. Tr another.anon.coward's pkg command. This usually returns the necessary include paths and libraries.

Comment: @another.anon.coward - Thank you! - it resolved this problem

Comment: @another.anon.coward - can you, please, write your answer as answer, so I can mark it as correct and this question won't stay without correct answer. (Or should I write the answer to it myself?) Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adding comment as response:
Please check if you have installed `check` framework. If so,  you could try using `pkg-config` say

```
gcc check_money.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs check`
```

Here `pkg-config` utility will read the `.pc` file (which happens to be `check.pc` in case of `check` framework, thus the last entry in the command says `check`) & add the necessary compiler flags (`--cflags` option) & libraries/linker options (`--libs` option)

Hope this helps!